# Both string and integer rules for a filed in laravel validation

Tags: laravel, validation

I want to validate a field that can be integer or string both.

When it is integer max value must be less than 30 and when it's string max value must be at most 10 character.

Is there any way to solve without make a custom rule? If not, what is the best algorithm for create this rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => [
        'required',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (is_int($value) && $value > 30) {
                $fail($attribute . ' must be less than 30.');
            } else if (is_string($value) && strlen($value) > 10 ) {
                $fail($attribute . ' must be less than 10 characters.');
            }
        },
    ],
]);
```

See Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#using-closures) for more info.